# Revoke execute privileges on insertion functions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-grant

I have database with role *viewer*:

```
CREATE ROLE viewer WITH NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE;
```

and also database schema called *i* (as for *i*nterface).
There are insert functions in schema *i*, i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM i.insert_machine(1,2,3);
```

inserts new row in table data.machine. There are some non-insertion functions, too, e.g. i.error_table(integer) which should be allowed to execute by user viewer. Grant options are:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA i TO viewer;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA i TO viewer;
```

I want to forbid user viewer to call these insert_* methods. How should I do it? If I try both:

```
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION i.insert_machine(int, int, int) FROM viewer;
REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION i.insert_machine(int, int, int) FROM viewer;
```

I am still able to run this method and get result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've find it out. I have to revoke execute rights from **public** and opt-in only specific roles:

```
REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION i.insert_machine(integer, integer, integer) FROM public;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION i.insert_machine(integer, integer, integer) TO writer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change owner to different role. It must be `eventviewer` at the moment.

Comment: Huh, my mistake, I am using viewer everywhere. Fixed.

Comment: I mean that owner of this function is either `viewer` role (or whatever else you want to revoke execute from) or owner is granted to `viewer` role. In this case changing permissions for this role will have no effect, since owner can change his own objects and so postgres grants permissions by default.

Comment: All tables and functions were created by _postgres_ user. GRANTs and REVOKEs are also done by _postgres_ user. Now I am connected as _viewer_ user and I am still able to execute these functions. Maybe I just don't follow what you mean.

Comment: Does this SQL return any rows? If yes, what roleid are there? `select roleid::regrole, member::regrole, grantor::regrole from pg_auth_members where member = 'viewer'::regrole::oid`

Comment: I think I get your idea. I removed grants from public and added them to specific user and now it works.

Comment: Oh, yeah, public as well. Can you post your solution as accepted answer so that those looking for unanswered questions won't see this one?